# window closed property returns false on close in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Following code works fine in Chrome but in Edge browser it is not working as expected.
childWin.closed property returns false on click of Confirm or Cancel button due to which returnValue couldn't be tested.
In chrome childWin.closed property returns true on click of Confirm or Cancel button.

Parent code:

```
childWin = window.open(child.xhtml,'',"dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:400px;center:yes;help:no;status:no");

childWin.onunload = function() {
      alert("childWin.closed="+childWin.closed);
        if (childWin.closed) {
            alert("childWin.returnValue in closed="+childWin.returnValue);

            if(childWin.returnValue != "confirm") {
                //Do clean up stuff
            } else {
                //
                childWin = window.open(url2,'',"dialogWidth:800px;dialogHeight:500px;center:yes;help:no;status:no");
                //
            }
        }
      }

Child.xhtml:
<BUTTON ONCLICK="window.returnValue = 'confirm'; window.close();">Confirm</BUTTON>
<BUTTON ONCLICK="window.close()">Cancel</BUTTON>
```

Comment: As a developer to developer, please use lowercase HTML tags and properties.

Comment: Especially if you save it to an xhtml file